# Qemu-Kvm Windows 7 Host Clock Speed Issue

Tags: speed, kvm-switch, clock

I've installed Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (x64) in a kvm virtual machine using virt-manager. Clock speed on the guest OS is going berserk. Everyhing is moving fast and the system time drifts which causes a lot of problems. This is the first time I am encountering this. I've installed Windows 7, 10 and various Linux distros befores, some of them I am still using, but I've never seen anything like this. What is the problem with this particular installation and how can I fix this?

Comment: It appears to be a bug with qemu 4.0. Check [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=246835).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using qemu 4.0, the cause of the problem is a bug.https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1704375

Just changing the machine type to 'pc-q35-3.1' to fixes it. See the example below.

```
<type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-4.0">hvm</type>
```